# Using Robolectric to test code that starts an activity

Tags: java, android, robolectric

I have some code I want to test with Robolectric. Basically I want to test that a button click launches an activity.

HomeScreenFragment.java:

```
public class HomeScreenFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button mSignInButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // call to super class
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup parent,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){

        // inflate view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_screen, parent, false);

        // handle sign in button
        mSignInButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // anonymous inner class
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SignInActivity.class);// start sign in activity with intent
                startActivity(intent); // <<== ERROR HERE WHEN RUNNING TEST

            }
        }
    }
}
```

My test looks like this:
HomeSreenFragmentTest.java:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class HomeScreenFragmentTest {

    private Activity mHomeScreenActivity;
    private Fragment mTestFragment;
    private Button mSignInButton;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception{

        mHomeScreenActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(HomeScreenActivity.class).create().get(); // start HomeScreenActivity, call through to onCreate()
        mTestFragment = mHomeScreenActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.home_screen_fragment_container);// get HomeScreenFragment

        // run onCreateView
        View testView = mTestFragment.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.from(mHomeScreenActivity),
                (ViewGroup) mHomeScreenActivity.findViewById(R.id.home_screen_fragment_container),
                null);

        // get button view
        mSignInButton = (Button)testView.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

    }

    // clicking sign in button should launch SignInActivity
    @Test
    public void testSignInButton2() throws Exception{
        mSignInButton.performClick(); <<=== ERROR STARTS HERE
        ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Robolectric.shadowOf(mHomeScreenActivity); // create shadow activity
        Intent startedIntent = shadowActivity.getNextStartedActivity();            // get intent of next activity on stack
        ShadowIntent shadowIntent = Robolectric.shadowOf(startedIntent);            // create shadow intent which starts next activity
        assertEquals(SignInActivity.class.getName(), shadowIntent.getComponent().getClassName()); // compare shadow intent w/ desired next activity
    }
```

The problem I am having is with the test. The code itself works fine in emulator/on device. The problem is that when Robolectric runs the `performClick()` method, and then gets to `onClick()` then goes to `startActivity(intent)` it fails.

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:3850)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:3825)
    at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:996)
    at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:975)
    at com.********.android.***project*****.controller.HomeScreenFragment$1.onClick(HomeScreenFragment.java:42)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
    at com.*********.android.***project***.HomeScreenFragmentTest.testSignInButton2(HomeScreenFragmentTest.java:83)
```

I know how to start an activity with Robolectric using the `Robolectric.buildActivity()` method. But this is for when I need an activity **in testing**. Why is Robolectric failing to run the `startActivity()` method in code? Is there a better way to test this?

Comment: This seems like an actual Robolectric issue. The normal `startActivity` methods are handled by the `ShadowContextWrapper` but a `Fragment` is not a `Context` like `Activity` and `Service` objects are so it blows up trying to run real android code. I filed this as issue [#767](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/767).

Comment: If you're interested in contributing to Robolectric, you could try forking it, writing a test for, and then creating the shadow method I described in the issue, and submitting a pull request. You can look at the other `startActivity()` methods for inspiration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should also call `.start().resume()` on your `ActivityController`, not only `.create()` This causes the fragment to be created as well.

If you do the above, you won't need to call `onCreateView` yourself. You can just get the button from the activity using `mHomeScreenActivity.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);`

In general I suspect your code fails because the fragment hasn't fully started yet, because you didn't call `start()` and `resume()`